# Chrome Extension IME sample error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ime

I am attempting to learn how to build a Chrome extension.  So this question has as much to do with that process, as the code itself.

I downloaded the sample code from here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:.ime (code below)

Then I browsed to chrome://extensions, enabled developer mode, and clicked load unpacked extension - and selected the directory with the below 2 files.

Loading the extension reports an error on line 9 of main.js (console.log("Initializing IME");) "anonymous function".

1. **Why does the code produce an error?**
2. **Did I load the extension correctly?**  (it doesn't appear to be activated, possibly due to the error?)
3. I can resolve the error by commenting out the offending line, but the extension still appears not to be activated.  **How do I activate it?**  (am I missing something?)

manifest.json:

```
{
 "name": "Test IME",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "A simple IME that converts all keystrokes to upper case.",
 "background":  {
   "scripts": ["main.js"]
 }, 
 "permissions": [
   "input"
 ],
 "input_components": [
   {
     "name": "Test IME",
     "type": "ime",
     "id": "test",
     "description": "Test IME",  // A user visible description
     "language": "en-US",  // The primary language this IME is used for
     "layouts": ["us::eng"]  // The supported keyboard layouts for this IME
   }
 ] 
}
```

main.js:

```
// Copyright 2013 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

var ime_api = chrome.input.ime;

var context_id = -1;

console.log("Initializing IME");

ime_api.onFocus.addListener(function(context) {
  console.log('onFocus:' + context.contextID);
  context_id = context.contextID;
});
ime_api.onBlur.addListener(function(contextID) {
  console.log('onBlur:' + contextID);
  context_id = -1;
});

ime_api.onActivate.addListener(function(engineID) {
  console.log('onActivate:' + engineID);
});
ime_api.onDeactivated.addListener(function(engineID) {
  console.log('onDeactivated:' + engineID);
});

ime_api.onKeyEvent.addListener(
function(engineID, keyData) {
  console.log('onKeyEvent:' + keyData.key + " context: " + context_id);
  if (keyData.type == "keydown" && keyData.key.match(/^[a-z]$/)) {
    chrome.input.ime.commitText({"contextID": context_id,
                                 "text": keyData.key.toUpperCase()});
    return true;
  }

  return false
});
```

Comment: where does the error show? seems its not an error, just the log. debug the background to find out.

Comment: Upon loading the extension, I see the error in the extension summary area. A little grey circle. The extension doesn't use a background.js.  in fact, I'm not sure what the background file is used for.

Comment: your manifest clearly shows a background file. Do make sure to first read the docs for Chrome extension arquitecture so you can first understand how the code you found might work, and thus what might be failing when you debug the background script.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem here is that the extension is an IME (keyboard)

There is an extra step to enable it.

> ```
> Settings | Language & input settings | Input Method | Select the newly installed IME and acknowledge the alert
> ```

Then use ctrl-alt-space to select the new input method.

All works as it should.

PS - and the "error" was not an error after all.

Comment: sorry could you please clarify where did you find "Input Method" under settings? I'm probably blind but I can't see anything like this under "Language & input settings", only list of languages.

Comment: yeah such a setting doesn't exist in the current version and installing Google Input Tools doesn't help either (extension is not listed).